# Rmarkdown to docx less-than symbol in table caption

Tags: r, r-markdown, docx, flextable

I would like to use the `<` symbol in a table caption of a Rmarkdown that converts to a docx document. I am using the `flextable` package as this gives a lot of (needed) flexibility to tables in the docx format.

But I am really confused by the multiple conversion steps through `pandoc`. It does not seem so easy to get to the `<` as it is a special coding HTML character. I have read that in HTML you would escape it via `&lt;`. This gives me the problem that the `&` has to be escaped, too. The conversion then turns `&lt;` into `&amp;lt;` (as it converts the `&` into `&amp;`) and `\\&lt;` would yield me `&amp;amp;lt;` (as it converts the `&` of the `&amp;` again). Latex does not seem to work either, I've tried `<`, `$<$` and `$\\textless$` but to no avail.

All combinations basically follow the same logic, i.e. that `<` are correctly transformed to `&lt;` but then the HTML is not converted again.

Any idea how to solve this? What do I miss?

Example RMD file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unkown"
date: "1/25/2021"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document, see Table \@ref(tab:test).


```{r test, echo = F}
flextable(head(cars, n = 10)) %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%
  autofit() %>% 
  set_caption("Table: (\\#tab:test) Example caption with less-than symbol: \\&lt; or &lt; or < or $<$ or $\\textless$")
```
````

Comment: If pdf, you should use `set_caption("Table: (\\#tab:test) ... < or >", html_escape = FALSE)`. Also make sure you are using the latest version as there were some fixes about your issue 2/3 releases before the current one (0.6.2)

Comment: Nice, thank you so much!! The ``html_escape`` works in docx, too! Thanks as well for the update suggestions, I will check the version(s) I'm running.

Comment: @DavidGohel Maybe you could help me out with another quick question: Why is the ``Table: (\\#tab:test)`` part printing ``Table Table 1:``? If I change anything it is does not understand the label at all though...

Comment: Maybe that would help: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/layout-1.html#captions

Comment: And don't define yourself (\\#tab:test), only add in the chunk option `tab.id="test"`

Comment: Works great with ``tab.id``, thanks again! You could post both as an answer for me to accept. Or should I answer it myself?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I'll answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer the question about `<` and `>` in the captions

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document, see Table \@ref(tab:test).


```{r test, echo = F, tab.id="test"}
flextable(head(cars, n = 10)) %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%
  autofit() %>% 
  set_caption("Example caption with less-than symbol: > and <")
```
````

You could use the package officedown. It will make the references as real Word references, it also offers few features to customize your captions:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::markdown_document2:
    base_format: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, tab.cap.style="Table Caption")
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r test1}
flextable(head(cars, n = 10)) %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%
  autofit() %>% 
  set_caption("Example caption with less-than symbol: > and <")
```


```{r "test2", tab.cap="Example caption with less-than symbol: > & <"}
flextable(head(cars, n = 10)) %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%
  autofit()
```



\newpage 

See \@ref(tab:test1).

See \@ref(tab:test2).
````

[image]

Comment: Awesome! And thanks for the tip to use officedown :)